# How to get only first data from a web scraping text List in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

> So i'm new to BeautifulSoup in python, and im trying to get (Scrape)
>   the latest version of python from their website (specifically their
>   downloads page) using BeautifulSoup, once i do that i get a list of
>   all the available python versions in a text format. But im trying to
>   get only the first element (which is Python 3.7.7) but i have no idea
>   how to do it, any suggestions?

```
page = requests.get("https://www.python.org/downloads/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
div_python_versions= soup.find('div', {"class": "row download-list-widget"})
python = div_python_versions.find_all('span', {"class": "release-number"})

for n in python:
    print(n.get_text())
```

As the output i get this on the terminal

```
Release version
Python 3.7.7
Python 3.8.2
Python 3.8.1
Python 3.7.6
Python 3.6.10
Python 3.5.9
Python 3.5.8
Python 2.7.17
```

All i want is to access the first element which is the (Python 3.7.7) and store it in a variable. It would helpful if anyone knows how to help in anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acess the second element on the list (first is "Release version")

```
python = div_python_versions.find_all('span', {"class": "release-number"})
First_element = python[1]
print(First_element.get_text())
```

Output:

```
Python 3.7.7
```

Comment: Thanks so much!, really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way, but this way will see if there is a substring `Python` on one element, if it doesn't iterate to next, if it exists, return:

```
page = requests.get("https://www.python.org/downloads/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
div_python_versions= soup.find('div', {"class": "row download-list-widget"})
python = div_python_versions.find_all('span', {"class": "release-number"})

var = ""
for n in python:
    if "Python" in n.get_text():
        var = n.get_text()
        break
print(var)
```

Or do it cleaner way by selecting only span release-number elements on tag `ol` and select the first element:

```
page = requests.get("https://www.python.org/downloads/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
ol_python_versions= soup.find('ol', {"class": "list-row-container menu"})
python = ol_python_versions.find_all('span', {"class": "release-number"})

var = python[0].get_text()
print(var)
```